# How to aggregate datapoints in a table?

Tags: sql, statistics, aggregate-functions, h2

Suppose I have following table -

```
CREATE TABLE data_points (t DATETIME PRIMARY KEY, value INTEGER);
```

I want to aggregate the data by calculating average of every 10 points in the table.

i.e. If table has 20 data points the result is two aggregate points. 1st aggregate point the average of 1-10 data points, and 2nd of 11-20.

Is this possible using a SQL query?

Comment: @PederN Divide the data in sets of 10 and run avg() function on each set.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this? Query works in MS SQL server.

```
SELECT AVG([VALUE]) OVER (PARTITION by par), * 
FROM (
    SELECT ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [VALUE]))-1)/10 par, * FROM TableName
)X
```

Comment: Which database is this for?

Comment: MS Sql server. Which is your database?

Comment: H2. But never mind. I'll understand the query and modify the syntax to make it run on H2. I'll mark this answer as selected once I get it working. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the link to know about the functions http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html.

Answer (score 0):

This one seem to do what you want in MYSQL.

```
SELECT 
    avg(value) as `average`, 
    10*FLOOR(value/10) AS `valueBucket`, 
    CONCAT(10*FLOOR(value/10),'-',10*FLOOR(value/10)+9) AS `range`
FROM 
    data_points 
GROUP BY
    valuebucket
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b4468/53/0

Comment: I think this solution is quite generic.. The main difference I think is how you concat the string for the 'range' value. Let me know how it works :)